# How to improve visibility of Omnibar on-the-fly search results?

Tags: google-chrome

With a recent release of Google Chrome, my extension icons have robbed the Omnibar of precious screen real estate.  On-the-fly search results are now truncated.

Is there any suggestion to improve this situation?  Can the extension icons be hidden, or moved to a lower row?

Screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hide the extensions by right-clicking on them and selecting the `Hide in Chrome menu` option:

[image: hide]

This will move them into the Hamburger (3 horizontal lines) menu:

[image: hidden]